# Fuzzing images (jpeg,png, etc formats) using Python

Tags: python, image, noise, fuzzing

I'm looking for a method/library to fuzz the image files.

The image files are accepted as an input to a python script (for object classification) that processes the image and returns an output (object class). I want to test the robustness of the object classifier here.
I've already looked into adversarial examples, what I'm looking for is script/library that modifies the image ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYAFi.png)) by adding random noise, flipping bits etc.. I found a C# implementation of this [here](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/08/generating-fuzzing-images-and-trying.html), I'm looking for a python/C++ implementation for the same.

I also checked [python-afl](https://github.com/jwilk/python-afl), I'm looking just to modify/randomize the image input and not to run any test on the code itself. So python-afl is not much of use to me.

Comment: I think you can do this with the PIL.ImageEnhance.Sharpness() method from Pillow.

Comment: Also second use of  Pillow

Comment: @JohnAnderson I want something like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYAFi.png) Not just adjusting the brightness/contrast